# New line in "valueFormatter"

Tags: react-native

I use the **react-native-charts-wrapper**.

My code:

```
              xAxis: {
                drawLabels: true,
                position: "BOTTOM",
                labelCount: 5, 
                valueFormatter: testobj.map(item => {
                  //test
                  return "a\nb";
                })
              }
```

[image]

Any idea, how can I use "\n" inside valueFormatter?

Comment: Have you tried return "a\nb" where \n is an actual new line, not the char?

Comment: @gkgkgkgk Thanks for reply! You mean "Template literals"? Yes, i tried.